# Jquery getJSON() doesn't get any output from Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an object from my controller and display in my JSP. On debugging my controller, the right data is returned. But when I use firebug to debug my javascript, the flow doesn't enter into function(data) of the getJson.

```
$.getJSON('/em',{name: name, cv: cv},
    function(data){
       alert("Hello");
       alert(data.name);
});
```

Controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/em", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Employee addEmployee(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,    @RequestParam(value = "cv", required = true) String cv,Model model) {
     return addedEm;
}
```

where I get addedEm returned correctly. Not sure what is going wrong here. Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Also, when I add @ResponseBody to my controller, I get the response at firebug:

```
Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 - Error report - <h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><u>The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u><b>exception</b> <pre>org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag[0]-&gt; nz.co.datacom.panelrequests.pd.user.Employee[&quot;user&quot;]-&gt; nz.co.datacom.panelrequests.pd.user.User[&quot;roles&quot;]-&gt; org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag[0]-&gt; nz.co.datacom.panelrequests.pd.user.Panelist[&quot;employees&quot;]-&gt;*
```

and then:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:189)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
            org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:442)
        org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:383)
        org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$AsArraySerializer.serialize(ContainerSerializers.java:142)
```

and then it gets repeated till the maximum limit of firebug.

Comment: Any body knows what the problem here is? i couldn't really find out a solution for this. :(

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because your entities have a reference to one another. Which is creating infinite recursion.  When jackson goes it reads one and then goes back to the other then back to that one etc.  Your employer has a reference to employee and your employee has a reference to employer.  OneToMany and ManyToOne

Here is a blog entry with a fix.
http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2010/10/json-jackson-to-rescue.html

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences

On a side note, you can also use the annotation @JsonIgnore to ignore certain fields of an entity if you don't want them included.